# How To Write A String(XML Node formatted without root) as nodes using XMLWriter in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, string, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I'm trying to write a string(which is nothing but XMLNodes) into a new XML File using XMLWriter

```
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\\Test.XML")
writer.WriteStartDocument();
writer.WriteStartElement("Test");

string scontent = "<A a="Hello"></A><B b="Hello"></B>";
XmlReader content = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(scontent));
writer.WriteNode(content, true);
//Here only my first node comes in the new XML but I want complete scontent
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

Expected Output :

```
<Test>
<A a="Hello"></A>
<B b="Hello"></B>
</Test>
```

Comment: If you're trying to write a `string`, why use an `XmlWriter` at all?  `File.WriteAllText` should work just fine.

Comment: @MikeStrobel I cannot use File.WriteAllText as I'm writing an XML element in between a Node. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify `ConformanceLevel` because your xml has no root element.

Also always should dispose all used resources.

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\\Test.XML"))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("Test");

    string scontent = "<A a=\"Hello\"></A><B b=\"Hello\"></B>";

    var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;

    using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(scontent))
    using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, settings))
    {
        writer.WriteNode(xmlReader, true);
    }

    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

In addition, you can use `XmlWriterSettings` to add indents.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... with `\` before `""`

```
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\\Test.XML")
writer.WriteStartDocument();
writer.WriteStartElement("Test");

string scontent = "<A a=\"Hello\"></A><B b=\"Hello\"></B>";
XmlReader content = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(scontent));
writer.WriteNode(content, true);
//Here only my first node comes in the new XML but I want complete scontent
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

Comment: if you're looking at escaping those characters, that isn't my intention. It shouldn't go as a XML Node Body but instead as a XML structure. Alex's solution worked. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: Cool... Happy Coding :)